# Finding files in a zip file using reg expression

Tags: java, regex

I cannot seems to form the right regular expression for my current issue.

I have a zip file and I'm looking through all the entries for files in  folder only.

Example

> supermans/underwear/picture.jpg

For the above example, I am looking for files in underwear folder only! (there could be other folders in "underwear"

I came out with this

```
String patternStr = "(.*)/underwear/([a-zA-Z])-/.([a-zA-Z])";
```

The first part seems to work.. it looks for scan until it see /underwear/ but the scanning for files only fails.

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the first problem is that your file lookup as it is now needs some changes. Not sure what the middel minus is, en the period should be escaped with backslah, no slash

```
String patternStr = "(.*)/underwear/([a-zA-Z])\.([a-zA-Z])"; 
                                              ^^
```

The second part is that you are looking for a series of characters, not single, so add iterator

```
String patternStr = "(.*)/underwear/([a-zA-Z]+)\.([a-zA-Z]+)"; 
                                             ^            ^
```

In addition, though, are your files only letters? Is that safe to assume. Are they alwasy a single word, a dot, and a single word? Not "abde01.gif" or a.b.c.gif? Once it works basic, may want to beef up a bit.

Comment: Also, all of the `.`s need to be replaced with `[^/]` to prevent matching longer paths.

Comment: I thought of that, @chrylis but he had mentioned that the directory part was working so not sure. Thanks!

Comment: is it possible to scan all the possible characters in a file name

Comment: not finding ones I really like in initial search, but this one seems good start "[0-9A-Za-z_ ]"

Comment: @user4127 Depending on the system in question, nearly anything can be legal. Most Linux filesystems permit every character except `NUL`, including the forward slash.